# How to get response in HTTP Header fields with Moya

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, moya

I have configured my provider like this:

```
lazy var provider: RxMoyaProvider<LiveNetworkAPI> =  {
    let endpointClosure = { (target: LiveNetworkAPI) -> Endpoint<LiveNetworkAPI> in
        let defaultEndpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
        return defaultEndpoint.adding(newHTTPHeaderFields: ["Device-System-Version": "iOS \(UIDevice.current.systemVersion)",
                                                            "Device-Version": Device.version().rawValue
            ])
    }
    return RxMoyaProvider<LiveNetworkAPI>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true), self.pluginLoading])
}()
```

But I don't know how to get response in HTTP header fields, I only can get fields in body.